# Destroy bootstrap-popover after mousedown event is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to destroy a specific popover when the `mousedown` event is completed. As long as the user presses on the mouse, the popover is visible. When the user isn't anymore, there should be a delay of let's say 3.5 seconds, then it should be destroyed.

My current implementation displays the popover correctly as long as the `mousedown` is true, but when I release the mouse, the popover is destroyed immediately, without a delay. What shoud I do?

jQuery:

```
function destroyPopover(selector)
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(selector).popover('destroy');
        }, 3500);
}   

...

$('#otp_table').on('mousedown', 'td', function() {
        $(this).popover({
                container: 'body',
                content: 'Lorem ipsum',
                placement: 'top',
            }).popover('show');
    }, hidePopover(this));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct my problem, I've added this line in the popover object:

```
delay: { "hide": 3500 },
```

which gives this...

```
$('#otp_table').on('mousedown', 'td', function() {
    $(this).popover({
            container: 'body',
            delay: { "hide": 3500 },
            content: 'Lorem ipsum',
            placement: 'top',
        }).popover('show');
}, destroyPopover(this);
```

also, I've removed the `setInterval` in my destroyPopover() function, which gives this...

```
function destroyPopover(selector)
{
    $(selector).popover('destroy');
}
```

Hope it will be useful!